# Webdriverjs/protractor iframe switching not work

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

One of my automation case has been blocked for more than 1 week, there is a lazy loaded iframe (clicking a link will insert this iframe into DOM), my code is like below:

```
driver.get("my url");
driver.findElement(By.linkText('REGISTER')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
    console.log("WAITING FOR EXTERNAL IFRAME");
    return driver.findElement(By.css("div#main-container > iframe")).isDisplayed();
}, 8000, "WAIT TIMEOUT!!!!");
driver.switchTo().frame(1); // The iframe has no id and I have no control
// Manipulating in the iframe
```

Whenever I manually do the operation above, I am 100% sure after clicking the "REGISTER" button, there are totally two iframes on the page, i.e. if I do `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")`, I can get two iframes! But during the automation running, it just always fails, I really don't know why, and more important, I did see debug tips for [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) and [webdriverjs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/dZFNOFYwzX8), however, I didn't figure out a good way to do the DOM query in the REPL, all because of webdriverjs' promise control flow, any experienced debugging tips here are highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle iFrame using three methods:

1. `driver.switchTo().frame(1)`;
2. `driver.switchTo().default`; - it will switch to the default iframe if its id isn't provided
3. `driver.switchTo().index(0)`; - it will switch to default first index

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But #1 I tried but not work, #2 not work as well, because the iframe i want is the second one, and #3, the method does not exists, I was using all the latest version of protractor/webdriver. Can you please try to automate the registration process on https://developer.autodesk.com

Comment: Hey just send me page source, I'll send you the complete steps

Comment: The page is developer.autodesk.com

Comment: Hi Wayne, Here we go with the registration code:

public class Registration {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://developer.autodesk.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn_oxygen_registration']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='oxygen-container']/iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='firstname_str']")).sendKeys("asdfadsf");
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Updated:There are 2 spaces in HTML with iframe : in of iframe, out of iframe.In of iframe there is a child document, child head, child body. When we have a iframe or many iframe, we want to do smt in iframe, we can: Using Element (widely used) or Using Index

1. Option 1

> driver = browser.driver;

```
var iframeElement = element(by.css('path_to_iframe');

browser.switchTo().frame(iframeElement.getWebElement());

driver.findElement(by.tagName('body')).click();  

driver.findElement(by.tagName('body')).sendKeys(string);
```

2. Option 2
   With first iframe: index is 0, second iframe index is 1, and go on...

> browser.switchTo().frame(0);

> browser.switchTo().frame(1);

Every done with a iframe, you need to switch out of the iframe. you need :

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: https://chercher.tech/protractor/frames-protractor#find-iframe-frame

Answer (score -1):

I work in Selenium-java. The following code worked perfectly for me.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://developer.autodesk.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("btn_oxygen_registration")).click();

WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://accounts.autodesk.com/register')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
driver.findElement(By.id("firstname_str")).sendKeys("EnterUsername");
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I know how to do that in Java/python, my problem is specific in js

Comment: try putting `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` then `driver.switchTo().frame(1);`